# saving id and value of inputs of form in an array

Tags: php

I have made an interface whereby the user can create his own form. I've just managed to load that form in a separate php file.

What I want to know is that after posting the form, how do I capture all the id and values of the inputs in an array so that I can display the the form (read-only) and display it on another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `<form>` `method` attribute is `post` - you send POST request to server. You can access all POST data through `$_POST` like `var_dump($_POST);`.

If your `<form>` `method` attribute is `get` or you have no `method` set - you send GET request to server. You can access all GET data through `$_GET` like `var_dump($_GET);`.

No matter which input fields was in form - they all would be here.

```
$post = array();

foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
 $post[$key] => $value;
}
```

But this example is not too good. It's not protected against SQL-injection - pay attention to it. But with it you can get all $_POST data in `$post` array.

Comment: Yes but my question is how to save that POST data since the field names are defined by the user, not hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

When you post a form, you have the "array" `$_GET` or `$_POST` according to the method (but you could use `$_REQUEST` which gets both post and get "arguments") where you have all the data you need to process the content of the form. The PHP [array_keys](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) returns the keys which are the names given for each field in the form. Using each key in a loop, you can do some kind of processing over the "content" of that field, that you can retrieve using the current key in the loop; e.g.

```
  foreach(array_keys($_GET) as $a)
  {
      echo $a . " => " . $_GET[$a];
  }
```